# Why am I getting "unwanted" log entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am starting to explore `Python 3.5`'s `logging` package. I set logging up with these two commands in the `main` file

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=r'fractal.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

In addition I inserted

```
import logging
```

in another module.
All my desired log entries showed up correctly in the log file, but in addition to those I got these two, which were not AFAIK generated by my logging code:

```
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): ichart.finance.yahoo.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com:80 "GET /table.csv?d=11&b=1&e=6&s=%5EIRX&g=d&c=1900&a=0&f=2016&ignore=.csv HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

These log entries were clearly not generated in the `main` module. Also, they do not show up when I set the logging level to `INFO`.

Does anyone know why I am getting these log entries? Are they evidence of problems with my code?

Comment: Look at what's being logged; it's very specific. You appear to have code running that queries yahoo for financial information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are setting the level of the *root logger*, and the `requests` module delegates all logging to it. You can fix this by explicitly shutting down the `requests` logger:

```
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

This will silence all the `DEBUG`-level messages from `requests`.

---

Alternatively you could use your own logger instead of relying on the root logger, there are various ways to do this (e.g. `logging.config.dictConfig` could be used) but you can easily do this manually, something along the lines of:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('fractal.log'))
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks! The first solution works perfectly and the second one works in the main module where the logger object is created. Other modules do not know about the existence of the logger object created in the main module. Do I have to add the same three lines in each module whose code execution I want to log?

Comment: @Soldalma It depends on how you are dealing with loggers. You typically want to do `import logging; logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in all your modules and use `logger.debug` or `logger.info`. You should *not* set any handlers inside the modules (typically), but only define the handlers in the main file (e.g. the script that actually runs the code). Please refer to the documentation for the `logging` module, there's a "cookbook" section that explains the "standard use cases".

Comment: Thanks again. I had to add all three commands to each module to make it work. But then I got unwanted red entries on the Run window, repeating what those that were logged to the file by code in the non-main modules. Without the setLevel command nothing is logged and without the addHandler command logging is only to the screen. I will look at the cookbook.